# Execute JavaScript from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, mono

I have an issue with https post request from C# on Mono, it is because TLS 1.2 unsuported by old version of mono. I have an idea to do it via JavaScript, so I need be able to pass JSON data to JavaScript and then get answer from JavaScript. Is it real to execute JavaScript from C#? If yes, can you provide please JavaScript function, which get JSON data and return JSON answer from server? Thanks to all

My general purpose is - send POST request to server, but old version of mono dont support TLS 1.2 and I am not able to update mono

Comment: Why JavaScript? Why not use some proper tool for it, like `curl`?

Comment: I tried to use curl, but it was very slow, near 15sec for query. I used it via process, maybe you mean abother way?

Comment: https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net

Comment: Your post is not totally clear. Why do you like to do it from JavaScript? For debugging?

Comment: I decide to do it by JavaScript, because I dont know another way. If you can suggest anything else - I will be glad to listen you.